# Displaying a number in excel without the leading zero

Tags: excel-2007

Is there a way to display a decimal number in Excel without the leading zero?

For example,

```
0.0220 would be displayed as  .0220
1.0220                    as 1.0220
and
10.0220                   as 10.0220
```

Is is the practice sometimes found in articles, and when doing tables and comparing data the leading zero can distract you. It would be useful if there was a way to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use a custom format like .00 (or ,00 depends on how numbers are defined in your country, for me it's ,00)

```
,24
10,23
,50
```

Hope it helps!

Best regards
KH.